# TestNG Unit Testing Tar and 7z

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, apache-commons, apache-commons-compress

[folder structure is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhhb6.jpg)

[console output is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fLiy.jpg)

I'd like to write a test class for the 2 methods below

```
package jfe;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.sevenz.SevenZFile;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils;

public class JThreadFile {

    /**
     * uncompresses .tar file
     * @param in
     * @param out
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void decompressTar(String in, File out) throws IOException {
        try (TarArchiveInputStream tin = new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(in))){
            TarArchiveEntry entry;
            while ((entry = tin.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                File curfile = new File(out, entry.getName());
                File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
                if (!parent.exists()) {
                    parent.mkdirs();
                }
                IOUtils.copy(tin, new FileOutputStream(curfile));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * uncompresses .7z file
     * @param in
     * @param destination
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void decompressSevenz(String in, File destination) throws IOException {
        //@SuppressWarnings("resource")
        SevenZFile sevenZFile = new SevenZFile(new File(in));
        SevenZArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = sevenZFile.getNextEntry()) != null){
            if (entry.isDirectory()){
                continue;
            }
            File curfile = new File(destination, entry.getName());
            File parent = curfile.getParentFile();
            if (!parent.exists()) {
                parent.mkdirs();
            }
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(curfile);
            byte[] content = new byte[(int) entry.getSize()];
            sevenZFile.read(content, 0, content.length);
            out.write(content);
            out.close();
        }
        sevenZFile.close();
    }

}
```

I use testNG and try to read from a folder, filter the folder for certain extensions (.tar and .7z) feed those files to the uncompress methods and compare the result to the actualOutput folder with AssertEquals. I manage to read the file names from the folder (see console output) but can't feed them to decompressTar(String in, File out). Is this because "result" is a String array and I need a String? I have no clue how DataProvider of TestNG handles data. Any help would be appreciated :) Thank you :)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class JThreadFileTest {

    protected static final File ACT_INPUT = new File("c:\\Test\\TestInput\\"); //input directory
    protected static final File EXP_OUTPUT = new File("c:\\Test\\ExpectedOutput\\"); //expected output directory
    protected static final File TEST_OUTPUT = new File("c:\\Test\\TestOutput\\");

    @DataProvider(name = "tarJobs")
    public Object[] getTarJobs() {

        //1
        String[] tarFiles = ACT_INPUT.list(new FilenameFilter()
        {
          public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
          {
            return name.endsWith(".tar");
          }
        });

        //2
        Object[] result = new Object[tarFiles.length];

        int i = 0;
        for (String filename : tarFiles) {
            result[i] = filename;
            i++;
        }
        return result;


    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "tarJobs")
    public void testTar(String result) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Running test" + result);
        --> JThreadFile.decompressTar(result, TEST_OUTPUT);
        Assert.assertEquals(TEST_OUTPUT, EXP_OUTPUT);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried the files list method by itself? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I managed to run it now. The problem was simply input directory path.

Comment: --> JThreadFile.decompressTar(result, TEST_OUTPUT); this is where I'm stuck at :/

Comment: What don't you use an existing library like `commons-compress` ? You wouldn't have to test it

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I use commons.compress.archivers.tar and sevenz already in class JThreadFile. I just have many test cases and wanna make sure the methods work fine with different file combinations before deploying to production.

Comment: Anyone who could help? :/ I'm still stuck at the same place :/

Comment: It seems like I was filtering a String array. I should have been using File[] with listFiles. Then everything worked out. I’ll post the working solution soon. Thank you for your time and help. :)